# discord.js has error with it's own library. How do I solve this

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

Trying to make a new discord bot with the newest version of discord.js, but it has problems with its own library.

My other bots work fine with an older version but I'd like to use the newer one. I just don't know why it's not working

This is the only code I've written myself so far

```
import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ]
});
```

It says it has found 4 errors. I just don't know what to do to fix them

```
node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1503:42 - error TS2344: Type 'MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]' does not satisfy the constraint 'ModalSubmitInteraction<CacheType> | MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
  Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | SelectMenuInteraction<...> | ModalSubmitInteraction<...>' is not assignable to type 'ModalSubmitInteraction<CacheType> | MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
    Type 'ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'ModalSubmitInteraction<CacheType> | MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
      Type 'ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
        Type 'MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
          Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | SelectMenuInteraction<...> | ModalSubmitInteraction<...>' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
            Type 'ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
              Types of property 'channel' are incompatible.
                Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is 
not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                  Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                    Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                      Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                        Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                          Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                            Type 'DMChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                              Type 'DMChannel' is missing the following properties from type 'ThreadChannel': archived, archivedAt, archiveTimestamp, _createdTimestamp, and 35 more.
                                Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                  Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                    Type 'DMChannel' is missing the following properties from type 'VoiceChannel': videoQualityMode, editable, speakable, nsfw, and 41 more.
                                      Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                        Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                          Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                            Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                              Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                                Type 'NewsChannel' is missing the following properties from type 'VoiceChannel': videoQualityMode, editable, speakable, setBitrate, and 8 more.

1503     } & MessageComponentCollectorOptions<MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]>;
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1511:49 - error TS2344: Type 'MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]' does not satisfy the constraint 'ModalSubmitInteraction<CacheType> | MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
  Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | SelectMenuInteraction<...> | ModalSubmitInteraction<...>' is not assignable to type 'ModalSubmitInteraction<CacheType> | MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
    Type 'ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'ModalSubmitInteraction<CacheType> | MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
      Type 'ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
        Type 'MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
          Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | SelectMenuInteraction<...> | ModalSubmitInteraction<...>' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
            Type 'ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'MessageComponentInteraction<CacheType>'.
              Types of property 'channel' are incompatible.
                Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is 
not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                  Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                    Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                      Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                        Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                          Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                            Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                              Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                  Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                    Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                      Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, 
TextBasedChannel>' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                        Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                          Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.

1511     } & MessageChannelComponentCollectorOptions<MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]>;
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1518:35 - error TS2344: Type 'MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Interaction<CacheType>'.
  Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | SelectMenuInteraction<...> | ModalSubmitInteraction<...>' is not assignable to type 'Interaction<CacheType>'.
    Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'Interaction<CacheType>'.
      Types of property 'channel' are incompatible.
        Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
          Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
            Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
              Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                  Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.                    Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                      Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.     
                        Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                          Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' 
is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                            Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                              Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                  Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.

1518       InteractionCollectorOptions<MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]>,
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1593:27 - error TS2344: Type 'MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Interaction<CacheType>'.
  Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | ButtonInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>> | SelectMenuInteraction<...> | ModalSubmitInteraction<...>' is not assignable to type 'Interaction<CacheType>'.
    Type 'MessageComponentInteraction<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>>' is not assignable to type 'Interaction<CacheType>'.
      Types of property 'channel' are incompatible.
        Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
          Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
            Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
              Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.
                  Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'GuildTextBasedChannel'.                    Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                      Type 'DMChannel | PartialDMChannel | NewsChannel | TextChannel | ThreadChannel | VoiceChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.     
                        Type '[If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                          Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw" | "cached"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' 
is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                            Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                              Type 'CacheTypeReducer<If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, GuildTextBasedChannel, TextBasedChannel>' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                Type 'GuildTextBasedChannel | ([If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends ["raw"] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : [If<Cached, "cached", CacheType>] extends [...] ? GuildTextBasedChannel : TextBasedChannel)' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.
                                  Type 'NewsChannel' is not assignable to type 'VoiceChannel'.

1593   ): InteractionCollector<MappedInteractionTypes<Cached>[T]>;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 4 errors.
```

btw koding it in Typescript, if that makes a difference

Comment: Have you tried updating all discord.js based libraries? Giant type errors like these are sometimes caused by outdated libraries

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you got this many error but you only wrote a short amount of code, most likely the problem came from the library itself because you've modified it or something.
To fix this you need to read the first line of your error which is:
`node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts`, as you can see at the second folder(`discord.js`), the library name is `discord.js`, that is what you need to reinstall.

to reinstall a library, It's pretty simple, what you wanna do is to type this command in your terminal:

```
npm uninstall discord.js
npm install discord.js
```

```
npm uninstall <libraryName>
npm install <libraryName>
```

Comment: It was a clean install of discordjs. Not edited at all. So trying to uninstall and installing it again didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this, is by simply ignoring it. It will not affect your code in any way, it will however ignore the error. Ignore the `node_modules` folder

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  // ...
  "exclude": ["node_modules"] // any other ignored folders/files can be provided here
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in an Array of the desired intents as IntentsStrings-- works just fine that way.

e.g.:

```ts
import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js";
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        `GUILDS`,
        `GUILD_MEMBERS`,
        `GUILD_MESSAGES`,
        `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`
    ]
});
```